# Showing terminating recursion for cumsum in Coq

Tags: recursion, coq, totality

I want to prove that computing the cumulative sum between `a` and `b` terminates.

I use an `Acc lt x` term to show that the recursion decreases, like this

```
Require Import Omega.

Lemma L1 : forall a b, a<b -> (b-(1+a)) < (b-a).
  intros; omega. Qed.

Lemma term_lemma: forall a b, Acc lt (b-a) ->  Acc lt (b-(1+a)).
    intros;  inversion H; clear H; constructor; intros; apply H0; omega.
Defined.

Fixpoint cumsum a b (H: Acc lt (b-a)) {struct H} : nat.
refine (
    match lt_dec a b  with
    | left a_lt_b => a + cumsum (1+a) b _
    | right a_ge_b => if beq_nat a b then a else 0
    end
  ).
apply (term_lemma _ _ H).
Qed.
```

It clears all subgoals but it won't typecheck at the `Qed` statement.  Coq complains:

```
Recursive definition of cumsum is ill-formed
Recursive call to cumsum has principal argument equal to
"term_lemma a b H" instead of a subterm of "H".
```

I guess I should somehow use `L1` to show that the argument in the `H` term in the recursive call is actually smaller, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you invert `H` before building something similar-ish back again by using `constructor ; apply H0`, you get a `term_lemma` with a pattern matching that's equivalent to what you'd want but confuses Coq's termination checker (You can inspect a term by using `Print NAME.`).

You don't need to do all of this inversion business if you remember that you already know that `a < b` thanks to your case analysis on `lt_dec a b`. By letting your lemma take an extra argument, you can now use the strict subterm of the `Acc`essibility predicate to get your witness:

```
Require Import Omega.

Lemma term_lemma: forall a b, a < b -> Acc lt (b-a) ->  Acc lt (b-(1+a)).
 intros a b altb [H]; apply H; omega.
Defined.

Fixpoint cumsum a b (H: Acc lt (b-a)) {struct H} : nat.
refine (
    match lt_dec a b  with
    | left a_lt_b => a + cumsum (1+a) b _
    | right a_ge_b => if beq_nat a b then a else 0
    end
  ).
apply (term_lemma _ _ a_lt_b H).
Defined.
```

Comment: Thanks! How should one think about these issues with inversion confusing the type checker etc. to avoid these problems in the future?

Comment: The whole purpose of the accessibility predicate is to provide you with a structurally smaller argument. Therefore the only way to ever use such an argument is to deconstruct it (my `intros (...) [H]` is doing that; cf [intro patterns](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual011.html#@tactic35)) and to apply its only premise (my `apply H` does that). If you start doing anything more complicated than that then there is a problem somewhere in your proof.